Read sample encrypted AAC with FFmpeg
I'm trying to open a sample encrypted AAC file (packed audio) using FFmpeg APIs.
I can open an unencrypted AAC file using
     AVFormatContext* iContext = nullptr;
     avformat_open_input(&iContext, mediaFileName.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr);

I'm also able to open a sample encrypted fmp4 segment using
     AVDictionary *options = nullptr;
     av_dict_set(&options, "decryption_key", ssKey.str().c_str(), 0);
     AVFormatContext* iContext = nullptr;
     int ret = avformat_open_input(&iContext, mediaFileName.c_str(), nullptr, &options);

But when trying to open a sample encrypted AAC file I find no way to set the decryption key. When using code snippet above, decryption_key option is not consumed by the demuxer which, according to documentation, means that it is not recognized by the aac demuxer.
An HLS asset with sample encrypted AAC audio track is playable in ffplay so it should be possible to open the format. Anyone has any pointers on how?

It seems as the case when e.g. ffplay is reading sample encrypted AAC is using an HLS demuxer which is decrypting each frame with the ffmpeg internal ff_hls_senc_decrypt_frame(). So I'm not sure it is possible to read sample encrypted AAC using the FFmpeg public API.
